# Swift 2 TapGesture Error: "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I've spent 2 days trying to get a single tap to work on a single view (clicking anywhere in the screen). I've tried every variation of fixing this problem I could find. Inside the DVC Class, with @IBActions on everything, renaming the view as an @IBAction etc. I can't get any other error except : "**[UIView score:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**"

```
class DataViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    var tappy = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    override func viewDidLoad() {

      self.tappy = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self.view, action:"score:")
      self.tapView!.addGestureRecognizer(self.tappy)

     }

}

func score(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer!) throws  {

    print("tapped")

}
```

Comment: You also need to pass `self` as the target, not `self.view`

Comment: Thank you! First App, I was afraid I had it wrapped in the wrong class or something. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem is that your `action:` selector, `"score:"`, doesn't correspond to what Objective-C sees when you declare your method as `func score(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer!) throws`. It sees `"score:error:"`. The simplest solution is to delete `throws`, since `"score:error:"` cannot be an action method signature for a tap gesture recognizer.

Moreover, as @dan has pointed out, `score` is not in `self.view` but in `self`. So you also need to change your `target:`.

Comment: Thank you! First App, I was afraid I had it wrapped in the wrong class or something. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If my answer was right, please consider accepting it (by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer). You don't have to, of course, but I notice you almost never accept any answers, which will make people reluctant to assist you on Stack Overflow.